# Прокрутка div колесиком мыши. Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Как скролить div с контентом внутри? Подскажите пожалуйста. Пробую так
HTML:

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)" class="context"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб элемент можно было скорллить, у него должна быть ограниченная высота и и правильны overflow.

Как-то так:

```css
.context {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

UPD

`(scroll)` тут ни при чём. Если вы не собираетесь писать специальную логику обрабатывающую события по скроллированию, то `(scroll)="..."` можно убрать.

Comment: В Вашем случае, появляется скролл бар, который смещает содержимое контейнера влево. Данный вариант не подходит. Я бы хотел, чтобы скролл бара не было, и можно было прокручивать div колесом

Comment: Можно спрятать скроллбар https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/